# Creating an Android todo list app: can a recyclerview be used to also show indented subtasks?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I've been building a todo app in Android studio and wanted to add subtasks as a functionality. The Google tasks app has this functionality and shows a subtask of a task to be indented as such: [image: Google tasks app]

They also allow you to drag subtasks out of the parent task and make it a normal task.
I've been searching everywhere, but cannot find out how this is implemented. Is this done/can this be done with a simple recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You should create a `RecyclerView` with `ViewHolder` (let's call it VH1). This `ViewHolder` will contain `RadioButton` and inner `RecyclerView`, which has `marginStart`. And inner `RecyclerView` `ViewHolder` will contain only `RadioButton`. `VH1` will have the method, which binds data to `View`, and here you just pass some structure like:

```
{
   "name": "Task3",
   "subitems": [
       "SubItem1",
        .....
   ]
}
```

Then just passing `subItems` data to inner `RecyclerView` and again bind it in it's `ViewHolder`

Comment: Ok, but then I wouldn't be able to drag the subtasks out of the parent task and make it a 'normal task' right?

Comment: @ReefG yes. My answer was to your question about RecyclerView with inner RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

Use the below library,
You can change the sub item position in the list after the drag finished by using setDataChangeListener.
Check the documentation
https://github.com/thesurix/gesture-recycler

-Change the radio button margin in runtime based on the position in your list
-To make the task a main task or a subtask while dragging, use the setSwipeEnabled method in the library and catch the user swipe whether it is left or right swipe and change the task level accordingly